# json query in if condition

Tags: java, sql, json

```
{
 "class": "premnath",
 "forInitiatorOnly": true,
 "text": "#if($payload.isUploaded)  ${payload.getModuleRef().moduleName()} 
          completed successfully.
          Number of records processed were ${payload.getNoOfRecords()} and 
          if(${payload.getThin()} !=0)} 
          number of thins are ${payload.getThin()}  
          #end"
}
```

in that `if` condition is not checking and i am getting output like this

```
module is uploaded successfully. Number of records:9 and (2!=0) number of thins:9
```

can u please tell how to check the condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(${payload.getThin()} !=0)}
```

The last } shouldn't be there, should it?